# Splitting Coordinates Read in from File Java

Tags: java, string, file

I'm having trouble splitting a line read in from a txt file in to two points. The file has a list of coordinates like this:

```
(0, 0) (1, 2)
(0, 1) (-3, 4)
....
```

What I'm trying to do is separate them into two separate points so that I can calculate the distance between them. The issue I have is splitting them into the points after that I think I have everything correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        String point1, point2;
        int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            point1 = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(")"));
            point2 = line.substring(line.indexOf(")"), line.length());

            x1 = Integer.parseInt(point1.substring(1, point1.indexOf(",")));
            y1 = Integer.parseInt(point1.substring(point1.indexOf(",") + 2, point1.length() - 1));

            x2 = Integer.parseInt(point2.substring(2, point2.indexOf(",")));
            y2 = Integer.parseInt(point1.substring(point2.indexOf(",") + 2, point2.length() - 1));

            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
            System.out.println((int)distance);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you might to generalize more your approach. The current one is not very robust, because it is very dependent on the file format (one more or one less space, and it fails)

Comment: @Joffrey Very true, I'm guessing though once I figure out how to split the line into the two separate points I'd be able to repeat that process for the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this I think. Not very efficient algorithm though.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(0, 0) (1, 2)";
    String[] rawCoords = s.split("\\) \\(");
    Point p1 = parsePoint(rawCoords[0]);
    Point p2 = parsePoint(rawCoords[1]);
    System.out.println(p1.distance(p2));

}

private static Point parsePoint(String s) {
    //remove all brackets and white spaces and split by comma
    String[] rawXY = s.replaceAll("[\\)\\(\\s]", "").split(",");
    return new Point(Integer.parseInt(rawXY[0]), Integer.parseInt(rawXY[1]));
}

public static class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double distance(Point another) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - another.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - another.y, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it's not the most efficient for what I'm doing regarding what you were doing with the points but how you split the string and separated the points is exactly the thing I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tokenizer

> (From the API) The string tokenizer class allows an application to break a string into tokens

Read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html